# Implied meaning of lower case latin letters $p$, $q$, $u$ etc. in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, notation

Are there any generalizations that should be assumed for (lower case) $p$, $q$ and $u$ in probability theory? For example, $q$ is often assumed to signify, in relation to $p$, that
$$
q=1-p.
$$
Is there a standard implied meaning/relation that should be made (unless stated otherwise) when encountering these lower case letters and and if so, what are the most common ones and their meaning/relation in a probabilistic setting?

EDIT: To clarify my question, I am interested in the implied meaning and/or relation of the *lower case letters* from the modern *Latin alphabet* such as $u$, not general notation practices with Greek symbols etc, in probability theory.

Answer (score 1):

In general, one should not rely on notation to be common across the literature, but nonetheless conventions exist. Here are a few that I am aware of:

**General**

- $i,j,n,m,k,l \in \mathbb{N}$ indices

**Probabilistic Setting**

- $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X]$: mean of a random variable $X$
- $\sigma = \text{Var}[X]$: variance of a random variable $X$
- $\Sigma = \text{Cov}(X)$: covariance matrix of a multivariate random variable $X$
- $\rho = \text{corr}(X,Y)$: correlation
- $r$: sample Pearson correlation coefficient
- $\theta$: parameter of a distribution
- $p$: probability mass function or probability density
- $f$: probability density
- $F$: cumulative density function
- $\phi$: characteristic function

Note: The letter $i$ is a good example of notation being used in different settings. It is often used to denote indices, but in a probabilistic setting in particular when using characteristic functions it refers to the [imaginary unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number).

Comment: $\phi$ is often used for the characteristic function, $F$ for the cumulative distribution function, as well.

Comment: I added your suggestions @ClementC.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, thanks for your answer, but I should have specified more clearly that I am only wondering about the lower case letters, such as the assumed meaning of $u$, not the general notation of probability

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. Out of interest, what is the implied meaning of ‘u’?

Comment: Good question, I recently encountered it in the context of being the $u$-quantile of a (loss) distribution, which was then implied to be analogous to the $(1-p)$-quantile of the same distribution. So I got curious why they did not use $q$ instead of $u$, and if maybe it had to do with the distribution being a *loss* distribution.

Comment: @litmus I often see $u$ denoting the **u**niform distribution (when the underlying domain is clear from context).